# How to integrate Sentry

Tags: go, sentry, buffalo

I want to catch all errors in the production environment and send them to the Sentry. But I can't understand how to add it as a middleware. Do I need to write a custom logger than implement logger.Logger interface or I can do it somehow differently?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the documentation? https://gobuffalo.io/en/docs/middleware#writing-your-own-middleware https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/go/guides/http/

Comment: I found this one https://github.com/stnguyen90/sentry-go/blob/buffalo-integration/buffalo/sentrybuffalo.go on the official sentry-go GitHub. It's not merged in the master but I want to try it tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, @martinni39 based on your code and code in the Buffalo manual I created this function:

```
func SentryLogger(lvl logger.Level) logger.FieldLogger {
l := logrus.New()
l.Level = lvl

levels := []logrus.Level{
    logrus.PanicLevel,
    logrus.FatalLevel,
    logrus.ErrorLevel,
}
hook, err := logrus_sentry.NewSentryHook("your sentry dsn", levels)
hook.StacktraceConfiguration.Enable = true
hook.StacktraceConfiguration.IncludeErrorBreadcrumb = true

if err == nil {
    l.Hooks.Add(hook)
}
return logger.Logrus{FieldLogger: l}
}
```

Then added to the buffalo options in the app.go

```
Logger:      SentryLogger(logger.DebugLevel),
```

Comment: Could you update and mark the answer as accepted

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you want a sentry logging middleware. Every big logging library should have their own middleware implementation. For example [logrus](https://github.com/evalphobia/logrus_sentry)

```
import (
  "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"
  "github.com/evalphobia/logrus_sentry"
)

func main() {
  log       := logrus.New()
  hook, err := logrus_sentry.NewSentryHook(YOUR_DSN, []logrus.Level{
    logrus.PanicLevel,
    logrus.FatalLevel,
    logrus.ErrorLevel,
  })

  if err == nil {
    log.Hooks.Add(hook)
  }
}
```

If you want to create your own (assuming you're using logrus), you'll have to implement the [interface for the hook](https://github.com/sirupsen/logrus/blob/master/hooks.go#L1-L11) and then post those entries yourself to sentry.